# Get a list of MCC Accounts

Tags: vb.net, google-ads-api

I have been struggling with the Google Ads Api to get the `MCC Accounts` for the last two weeks but I am unable to achieve what I want.

I have the App.Config figured out

```
<GoogleAdsApi>
    <!-- API-specific settings --> 
    <add key="DeveloperToken" value="XXXXXXX"/>

    <!-- OAuth2 settings -->
    <add key="AuthorizationMethod" value="OAuth2" />
    <add key = "OAuth2ClientId" value = "XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    <add key = "OAuth2ClientSecret" value = " XXXXXXX  " />
    <add key = "OAuth2Mode" value="APPLICATION"/>
    <add key = "OAuth2RefreshToken" value = "1//0gd2 XXXXXXX  " />
</GoogleAdsApi>
```

This is the code that I am currently working with

```
Public Sub GetMCCAccounts(ByVal client As GoogleAdsClient)
    Dim customerService As CustomerServiceClient = client.GetService(Services.V8.CustomerService)
    Dim customerResourceNames As String() = customerService.ListAccessibleCustomers()

    For Each customerResourceName As String In customerResourceNames
        Dim ManagerCustomerId = customerResourceName.Substring(customerResourceName.IndexOf("/") + 1)
        TextBox1.AppendText(vbCrLf & ManagerCustomerId)
    Next
End Sub
```

I am not getting the correct results. The MCC accounts that I was hoping for do not appear in the output. I am getting different account numbers. What am I missing?

**Expected MCC Accounts**

I am looking for these 10 MCC accounts.

[image]

**Sub Account Settings Overview**

[image]

**Output**

I am getting these 16 account numbers.

```
64xxxxxxxx
71xxxxxxxx
10xxxxxxxx
88xxxxxxxx
32xxxxxxxx
58xxxxxxxx
31xxxxxxxx
73xxxxxxxx
98xxxxxxxx
22xxxxxxxx
48xxxxxxxx
37xxxxxxxx
98xxxxxxxx
94xxxxxxxx
88xxxxxxxx
43xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 3):

After burning the midnight oil, I finally managed to crack it!

This finally gave me the MCC accounts that I wanted.

```
Imports Google.Ads.GoogleAds.Lib
Imports Google.Ads.GoogleAds.V8.Services
Imports Google.Ads.GoogleAds
Imports Google.Ads.GoogleAds.V8.Resources
Imports Google.Api.Gax
Imports Google.Apis

Public Class GoogleAdsCode
    Private Const PAGE_SIZE As Integer = 1000

    '~~> Get MCC Accounts
    Public Shared Function GetMCCAccounts(MgrId As Long?) As List(Of String)
        Dim googleAdsClient As New GoogleAdsClient
        Dim googleAdsServiceClient As GoogleAdsServiceClient = googleAdsClient.GetService(Services.V8.GoogleAdsService)
        Dim customerServiceClient As CustomerServiceClient = googleAdsClient.GetService(Services.V8.CustomerService)
        Dim seedCustomerIds As New List(Of Long)
        Dim MgrList As New List(Of String)

        seedCustomerIds.Add(MgrId.Value)

        Const query As String = "SELECT
                                    customer_client.client_customer,
                                    customer_client.level,
                                    customer_client.manager,
                                    customer_client.descriptive_name,
                                    customer_client.currency_code,
                                    customer_client.time_zone,
                                    customer_client.id
                                FROM customer_client
                                WHERE customer_client.level <= 1"
        Dim customerIdsToChildAccounts As Dictionary(Of Long, List(Of CustomerClient)) = New Dictionary(Of Long, List(Of CustomerClient))()

        For Each seedCustomerId As Long In seedCustomerIds
            Dim unprocessedCustomerIds As Queue(Of Long) = New Queue(Of Long)()
            unprocessedCustomerIds.Enqueue(seedCustomerId)
            Dim rootCustomerClient As CustomerClient = Nothing

            While unprocessedCustomerIds.Count > 0
                MgrId = unprocessedCustomerIds.Dequeue()
                Dim response As PagedEnumerable(Of SearchGoogleAdsResponse, GoogleAdsRow) = googleAdsServiceClient.Search(MgrId.ToString(), query, pageSize:=PAGE_SIZE)

                For Each googleAdsRow As GoogleAdsRow In response
                    Dim customerClient As CustomerClient = googleAdsRow.CustomerClient
                    If customerClient.ToString.Contains("MCC") Then MgrList.Add(customerClient.Id & " (" & customerClient.DescriptiveName & ")")
                Next
            End While
        Next

        Return MgrList
    End Function
End Class
```